# Dynamic changes to Twilio Flex Elements

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

During Twilio's SIGNAL 2018, one of the demos showed adding a sentiment based emoticon to tasks.  Can you provide a similar plugin sample?

Or, provide a simple sample showing, for example, how to dynamically change the background color of TaskCanvasHeader based on an attribute of the selected task?

Comment: I am trying to find these examples for you now, as flex is still new these examples will start to appear more frequently, but I'm not sure where they live right now. You might find the documentation for the [Flex UI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-overview-ui-programmability) and for the [flex-plugin-builder](https://github.com/twilio/flex-plugin-builder) useful though.

Comment: I am told that there is a blog post in the works to walk through the plugin from the keynote, so keep an eye on [the Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/) for news on this.

Comment: thanks @philnash - I've been through those resources and will keep a look out on the blog!